# why is omniauth initializing twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am attempting to add facebook authentication to my site. So far I've added:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {:provider_ignores_state => true}
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', :to => 'sessions#create', as: 'callback'
```

**app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    render :text => request.env['omniauth.auth'].inspect
  end
end
```

My issue is that the initialization seems to be running twice. In the logs for the rails server I see:

```
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

When I run `rake middleware` I see `OmniAuth::Builder` two times. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: dont suppose you are using Devise aswell are you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Richlewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150534/richlewis) was referring to, if you are using Devise with OmniAuth you need to skip the extra omniauth.rb initializer and simply config.provider "KEY", "SECRET" inside of initializers/devise.rb and then carry on with your implementation.

Comment: Using devise moves the authentication path from /auth/:provider to /users/auth/:provider.

Comment: Eventhough I have no omniauth.rb file omniauth request phase initiated twice.                                              Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-12 10:05:42 +0530
I, [2014-02-12T10:05:42.046501 #4240]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-12 10:05:42 +0530
I, [2014-02-12T10:05:42.402859 #4240]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.

Comment: This was huge. I was troubleshooting this forever focused on the CSRF error that resulted from multiple authentication attempts

Comment: I hit the same problem, and will just let people know, that the reason was I together with the device omniauth config also had a `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` file, so it was configured twice.